# Image alt tags for many images of same thing

Tags: images, alt-attribute

I have website with boats rentals. Each boat has at least 15 images.

Example 1 boat has large bedroom and 5 images are of bedroom from different angles.

I set up `alt` tags like this but I am not sure if this is good or spam for Google:

> 1. boat name - bedroom 1
> 2. boat name - bedroom 2
> 3. boat name - bedroom 3
> 4. boat name - bedroom 4
> 5. boat name - bedroom 5

There is not much to add to each image that I can think of, but I am sure each image is needed to give user as much information possible before renting.

Also there are several boats that are from same manufacturer and same model. Images are different but structure of boat is same, so I can not think of anything better but to repeat alt as I have written in example above.

Please advise.

Comment: If there's nothing more that could be said for each image then your alt tags are perfectly valid. However, if you can expand them then by all means do as it will help, for example "Boat Name - Bedroom with double bunk beds" etc. Best practice for alt tags is to use them what they was originally designed for, impaired users i.e blind people, if your alt tags are used in this manner everything else falls into place. Forget alt tags for search engines, think of your alt tags for your users.

Comment: Simon is perfectly correct. Google does not put much, if any, weight on alt text. It is a semantic clue for the image and does only somewhat/slightly speak to the content. Your alt tags should be descriptive of the image. For this, it would be best to describe the image the best that you can using a sentence for the benefit of users and for the benefit of image search. Image alt tags have relatively no effect on SEO otherwise and therefore no reason to be punished for bad alt text. The alt text is an attribute and not content.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an image sitemap and describe content and alt tags.
It will help you to get image indexed and better positioning of your images.

To get images indexed and custom sitemap, you can try several tools including custom coded program to develop sitemap with links, images and videos with all necessary details